# How to pass custom html tag to jquery-confirm?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm having this issue lately and I have no clue how to fix it..

I'm using `jquery-confirm` to display a notification when `Ajax` call ends.

This is my html block

```
<td>
  <a id="myID" data-header="{% item.name %}" name="myName" class="btn btn-xs btn-info" href="{% url 'start_server' item.id %}">
    <span class="fa fa-signal"></span>
  </a>
</td>
```

I want `data-header` from my html

This is my `ajax` call

```
$('a[name=myName]').click(function () {
    $('#loader').fadeIn();
    alertify.success('please wait...');
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "",
        success: function (d) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#loader').fadeOut(1500);
            }, 2000);
        }
    });
});
```

This is my `jquery-confirm`

```
    function myFunction(msg) {
   var lHeader = attributes.getNamedItem("data-header") ? this.attributes.getNamedItem("data-header").value : "ALERT!";
    $.confirm({
        title: lHeader,
        content: msg,
        icon: 'fa fa-exclamation-circle',
        type: 'red',
        typeAnimated: true,
        buttons: {
            cerrar: function () {
            }
        }
    });
    }
```

Basically,

I want to display my `lHeader` at the end of the execution, but it's not working.

The error I'm getting

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getNamedItem' of undefined

Can someone help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can access data attributes using data method of jquery, so use this:

```
function myFunction(msg) {
    var lHeader = $('a[name=myName]').data("header") || "ALERT";
    ...
}
```